# How to save edited text on refresh?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a React component called "EdiText". Right now, I can save the text, but if I refresh the page it goes back to its initial value. I want to save and keep the edited value even after a page refresh.

My code is the following:

```
const Project = ({ project, onDelete}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handleSave = (val) => {
        console.log('Edited value ->', val);
        setValue(val);
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="project-component">
                    <EdiText 
                    type="text" 
                    className="project-title" 
                    value={project.title} 
                    onSave={handleSave} 
                    showButtonsOnHover
                    submitOnUnfocus
                    cancelOnUnfocus
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <EdiText 
                    type="textarea" 
                    className="project-description" 
                    value={project.description} 
                    onSave={handleSave} 
                    showButtonsOnHover
                    submitOnUnfocus
                    cancelOnUnfocus
                    />
                    <Link to={`/projectpage/${project.id}`} className="view-icon"><FaEye/></Link>
                    <FaTrash className="delete-icon" onClick={() => onDelete(project.id)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [custom hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) for this.

```
// Hook
function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });
  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      // Save state
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      // Save to local storage
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

Store it onto another file and import and use like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useLocalStorage('')
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but when I update the title, the description updates too.

Comment: @George You should have separate state for the title and the description and have separate update function for each.

Comment: Well, I created two functions: ```const handleSave = (val) => {
        console.log('Edited value ->', val);
        setTitle(val);
    } ``` and another one called ```handleEdit``` for the description. In the EdiText component I also added ```onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.title)``` and a separate one for description, but when I edit one, both values change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage`:

```
const handleSave = (val) => {
    console.log('Edited value ->', val);
    localStorage.setItem('value', val)
    setValue(val);
}
```

And when the component first renders:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const storedVal = localStorage.getItem('value')
  if(storedVal) setValue(val)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `localStorage`:

```
const Project = ({ project, onDelete}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(localStorage.getItem('value'))

    const handleSave = (val) => {
        console.log('Edited value ->', val);
        setValue(val);
        localStorage.setItem('value', val)
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="project-component">
                    <EdiText 
                    type="text" 
                    className="project-title" 
                    value={project.title} 
                    onSave={handleSave} 
                    showButtonsOnHover
                    submitOnUnfocus
                    cancelOnUnfocus
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <EdiText 
                    type="textarea" 
                    className="project-description" 
                    value={project.description} 
                    onSave={handleSave} 
                    showButtonsOnHover
                    submitOnUnfocus
                    cancelOnUnfocus
                    />
                    <Link to={`/projectpage/${project.id}`} className="view-icon"><FaEye/></Link>
                    <FaTrash className="delete-icon" onClick={() => onDelete(project.id)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```